# hook_menu_alter() doesn't work

Tags: 6, routes

I have implemented `hook_menu_alter()` in a module I have created. I have printed something inside that function call but nothing shows up, alhough the `hook_init()` implementation from the same module is executed.

somebody has any idea regarding this issue?

```php
function mymodule_init(){
  print "here";
}

function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  print "I am here";
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: not sure but try removing the print statement from the init function. It Performs setup tasks. To see if the init was called or not you can use watchdog.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_menu` and `hook_menu_alter` are only called when rebuilding the menu table, not on each table load.  So you won't see your print statements.

As a side note, I would use `drupal_set_message()` rather than print when debugging.